# ajax returned data not recognizing HTML tags

Tags: html, ajax, jquery, handlebars.js

I have a jquery function that is pulling data back from a PHP/MYSQL script. The data has a `<br>` as part of the data string. When I append this to the DOM using `jQuery.append()`, it is not rendered as correctly as a `<br>`.

I am using Handlebars to insert the data into the DOM.

The append to the dom:

`$('ul.special-deals').append(template(item));`

The data string:

*Free Italian meat balls and spaghetii* `<br>` *when you spend over 10 Euros*

The output is just that:

*Free Italian meat balls and spaghetii <br> when you spend over 10 Euros*

The `<br>` is not recognized by the page.

Template:

```
<li> 
    <a href="#" class="restaurantItem" restaurant={{item.estName}} address={{estAddr}}>
        <img src="{{img_link}}" width="60" height="60" alt=""/>
        <div class="img-det">
            <strong class="title">{{title}}</strong>
            <p>{{desc_short}}<br/>
                Expires: {{expiry_date}}
            </p>
            <em class="price">{{price}}</em> 
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href='dealDetail.html?id={{id}}' class="det-link">Detail</a>
</li>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: When  you get your ajax respose, console.log(MyReponse); and then copy it into your question please

Comment: did you try using `<br/>` ? Same problem in multiple browsers?

Comment: Is this `<br>` contained within `desc_short`? Have you tried using triple braces (`{{{desc_short}}}`)?

Comment: Connor here is the output in chrome below:1: Object
desc_long: "Long description"
desc_short: "Free Italian meat balls and spaghetii <br>  when you spend over 10 Euros"
estAddr: "Strada Episcopiei 1-3, Bucharest 010292"
estName: "Roberto's, Athenee Palace Hilton Hotel"
expiry_date: "2013-05-01"
id: "2"
img_link: "images/special2.jpg"
price: " "
restID: "2"
title: "Free Starter"
view_count: "10"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: What about using the <pre> tag?

Comment: Pedro Ferreira, This works nicely, thank you

Comment: @PedroFerreira convert your comment into an answer :)

Comment: I've done that. Waiting for OP to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this `<br>` contained within `desc_short`?

If that's the case, have you tried using triple braces?

```
<p>{{{desc_short}}}</p>
```

This will output the contents without any HTML escaping, which is what you need in this case.